# How to make a Sphinx project on Jython?

Tags: java, python-sphinx, jython

I am trying to make a Sphinx documentation on Jython. I was able to install sphinx on the installed jython, but when I run the sphinx quickstart program I get:

```
C:\jython2.7.0\bin>sphinx-quickstart.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\runpy.py", line 161, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\bin\sphinx-quickstart.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\sphinx\cmd\quickstart.py", line 44, in <module>
    from sphinx.util.template import SphinxRenderer
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\sphinx\util\template.py", line 17, in <module>
    from sphinx.jinja2glue import SphinxFileSystemLoader
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\sphinx\jinja2glue.py", line 14, in <module>
    from typing import Any, Callable, Iterator, Tuple  # NOQA
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\typing.py", line 1302, in <module>
    class Generic(object):
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\typing.py", line 1035, in __new__
    if (isinstance(base, GenericMeta) and
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded (Java StackOverflowError)
```

Any ideas on what to do?

Also, I got these errors when I installed Sphinx on jython:

```
SyntaxError: ("Non-ASCII character in file 'C:\\Users\\NicoleM\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip_build_NicoleM\\Jinja2\\jinja2\\_identifier.py', but no encod
ing declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details",)

Compiling C:\Users\NicoleM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_NicoleM\Jinja2\jinja2\asyncfilters.py ...
SyntaxError: ("no viable alternative at input 'def'", ('C:\\Users\\NicoleM\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip_build_NicoleM\\Jinja2\\jinja2\\asyncfilters.py',
 7, 6, 'async def auto_to_seq(value):\n'))

Compiling C:\Users\NicoleM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_NicoleM\Jinja2\jinja2\asyncsupport.py ...
SyntaxError: ("no viable alternative at input 'def'", ('C:\\Users\\NicoleM\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip_build_NicoleM\\Jinja2\\jinja2\\asyncsupport.py',
 22, 6, 'async def concat_async(async_gen):\n'))
```

But after I got:

```
Successfully installed sphinx docutils sphinxcontrib-websupport requests packaging typing Jinja2 snowballstemmer alabaster Pygments babel imagesize six urllib3 idna certifi chardet pyparsing MarkupSafe pytz
```

Comment: Version of Sphinx?  How did you install it?  (BTW, my own experience with Jython + Sphinx has been full of Java StackOverflowError.)

Comment: @DavidCharles The version I installed is sphinx 1.7.6. I went to jython2.7.0\bin and installed it using `jython -m pip install sphinx`. Ah okay, so it's not just me.